# I need to make a trace of race track in c# winform app, that I can add and move points on it but can't find any tutorial for that

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am making an UI for our telemetry in winform application. I want to add a track trace like F1 team mclaren-mercedes did it in past. We're getting two double type location variables from our gps module on our car. Example: "40.742665, 29.783323". I'm looking for a way to identify the location of my point in this trace and move it when we get data from our gps module.
[in this picture, they add two arrow markers of their cars and they are moving it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdAJU.jpg)
I want to do the same thing as they did here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to really give an answer, suffice to say that in order to do this you will need to have a datum point to work from.

Initially I'd suggest that you use only the latitude and longitude coordinates, ignoring any other GPS data that you receive but do choose a datum point that is on or near to the track.

Treat the track as a sheet of graph paper and have a datum point say in one corner - it may be "40.000000, 29.000000".

Plot all of your gathered coordinates relative to this e.g. 40.742665, 29.783323 becomes 0.742665, 0.783323. You'll obviously need to use some scaling to make that integer values.

There will be some inaccuracy in the GPS and even if stationary the location may appear to change, so you'd typically use some other telemetry to help with that.

If you wish to show a race car relative to the track then you'll need a full set of coordinates for the track layout first.